# Using pre_get_posts with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I was reading [Stephen Harris](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris)'s excellent answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts?newsletter=1&nlcode=66447%7C9502) regarding the use of `WP_query()`, `query_posts()` and `pre_get_posts`.

He says *"pre_get_posts is a filter, for altering **any** query. It is most often used to alter only the 'main query'."*

It is possible to use `pre_get_posts` to filter **only** a specific secondary query created with `WP_Query`? eg.

```
$my_secondary_loop = new WP_Query(...);
if( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ):
    while( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ): $my_secondary_loop->the_post();
       //The secondary loop
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way is to add the action right before the query and [remove it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) immediately after.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'some_function_in_functionsphp');
$my_secondary_loop = new WP_Query(...);
remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'some_function_in_functionsphp');

if( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ):
    while( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ): $my_secondary_loop->the_post();
       //The secondary loop
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**EDIT**

Another technique you can use is to set your own query var and check for that in a hook:

```
// tell WordPress about our new query var
function wpse52480_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_special_query';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse52480_query_vars' );

// check if our query var is set in any query
function wpse52480_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['my_special_query'] ) )
        // do special stuff

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse52480_pre_get_posts' );
```

and in the template:

```
// set the query var (along with whatever others) to trigger the filter
$args = array(
    'my_special_query' => true
);
$my_secondary_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Milo. This is really very helpful. I always wondered if it was possible to set your own query var.

Comment: How can I use this trick for archive page? I don't want to rewrite the whole query again for archive page but want to use this technique.

Answer (score 4):

> #### `pre_get_posts` fires for every post query:
>
> - get_posts()
> - new WP_Query()
> - That random recent posts widget your client installed without you knowing.
> - Everything
>
> -- @nacin

With that being said unless you exclude your filter use the conditional: `is_main_query()` then your filter will fire on your new WP_Query.

If you only want to target your specific new WP_Query then there is no way to do that.

Comment: What about Milo's technique? I've never seen it before...

Comment: His technique will work.  Ive never used it for pre_get_posts but have for other filters like posts_where

Comment: Cool, something new learned today!