# is_home() and is_front_page() not working in sidebar

Tags: sidebar, homepage, conditional-tags

I'm trying to display a custom widget in the sidebar of my homepage (which is a static front page defined in `Settings > Reading`). Here is the relevant part of my `sidebar.php`:

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_lecture' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_lecture' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php 
endif;
```

The sidebar does not display because the conditional tag does not recognize my homepage as being a homepage.

When I `print_r($wp_query)` in the sidebar, it reveals that `[is_page] => 1` and that the post's `[ID] => 32`, which is correct. However, `[is_home]` is null.

For the record, I did use a custom query (`query_posts()`) in my `page.php` template, but I did reset it afterwards using `wp_reset_query()`.

Any pointers?

Comment: `is_home` being null on a static front page is correct, `is_front_page` is the one you should be looking at. also, `query_posts` should never be used, use `WP_Query` instead and polluting the global query object will be a non-issue.

Comment: Put a exit( 'working' ); right after if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) { to make sure the issue isn't with your sidebar...So do this if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) { exit('working'); } to test...

Comment: @Milo & @splashingpixels: thanks for the tips, problem solved. You are correct, `is_front_page()` is matching correctly. I was confused because when I `print_r($wp_query)`, `is_front_page` does not even show up as a property, while all the rest of the conditional tags are there. If it's not in the WP_Query object, then where is the "is_front_page" flag set?

Comment: and if one of you wants credit for the answer, add an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @Milo: won't adding a new WP_Query object reduce the page-load speed? My assumption was that simply modifying the existing query would yield better performance than running a separate query.

Comment: @JPLew - `is_front_page` is determined by checking the ID of the page against the ID stored in the `page_on_front` option, you can see it in source in `wp-includes/query.php`.

Comment: @JPLew - as for `query_posts`, if you are modifying the main query, use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, if it's a query in addition to the main, use `WP_Query`. The main query happens long before the template is loaded, so any use of `query_posts` in the template will run a new query and overwrite the original.

Comment: @Milo: great, thanks for the insights! Hehe, I just noticed you have a great answer on the topic here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/using-pre-get-posts-with-wp-query/52482#52482

Comment: Using `query_posts` will result in (much) worse performance than using `WP_Query` (for custom, seperate queries) or `pre_get_posts` (for modifying the main query)

Comment: Please add an answer ans accept it if you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but found an [anwser](http://www.eleventhmedia.com/web-design/wordpress-is-your-is_front_page-not-working-in-your-side-bar/) that worked for me. When you use `wp_reset_query();` before you use `is_home();` or `is_front_page();` it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can missing the semicolon at the end of the code. please replace the code with my code.

```
       if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
           if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_lecture' ) ) : ?>
                <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_lecture' ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php 
            endif;
        }
```

I hope it's work.