# pre_get_posts with WP_Query to prevent posts from specific tags

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/using-pre-get-posts-with-wp-query) about how to change a specific query but can't find a way to do the following:

1. I have several queries on homepage retrieving posts from categories, posts from "New"s, posts from "Recipes", posts from "Promo" etc
2. I have a slider area at the top that display posts from all categories that uses the tag "featured"

**How can I prevent all other queries on home from retrieving posts using "featured" tag so posts using the tag do not show up at the same time on the others queries?**

Obviously to change LL the other queries to not include posts using the tag would do, but to change the queries through `pre_get_posts` seems quite more neat.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems I foresee here. I'm assuming the featured portion is a meta value of some sort. We can run a conditional that will run for *all* queries on the Front Page but it would override the meta_queries instead of append to them. The hook would look something like this:

```
/**
 * Modify Theme Queries
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query
 *
 * @return void
 */
function theme_pgp( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $query->is_front_page() ) {

        if( false !== $query->get( 'post', false ) ) {
            $query->set( 'tag__not_in ' => array( 'Featured_Slug_ID' ) );
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know what your post type slug is or what your featured meta key is so it's a little difficult to create an exact exclusion query. Hopefully the above points you in the right direction though.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I'm not using meta keys or post types, just default posts

Comment: @Diana What is defining which posts are "featured" and which posts are not? Sticky posts?

Comment: a post tag "featured"

Comment: Try that, replace the `Featured_Slug_ID` with the ID of the featured tag.