# Using pre_get_posts to target a query in the sidebar

Tags: query, page-template

I know that `pre_get_posts` can be used to target a query on the main site, custom post types and pages. But is there a way to target a query in a sidebar? Right now, I'm using 'is_page_template()` but it's only using the main query.

Code on my `functions.php` template:

```
function opby_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set('tax_query', array(
    array('taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),
    'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
    ),
    array('taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'post-format-status' ),
    'operator'=> 'NOT IN')
    )
    );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
}
if ($query->is_page_template('sidebar.php')) {
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
    array('taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),
    'operator'=> 'IN'
    )));
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
}
return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'opby_query' );
```

The sidebar is using the default loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title();?><br>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The default loop is the main query. If you want a second query that does something different why not just create a new query. You seem to be repeating the main query everywhere then filtering with `pre_get_posts` rather than just creating new queries.

Comment: I'm trying to keep everything under one query and that's the purpose of `pre_get_posts` is that you can target the `main_query` and a query on `pages.php` and another query on a `custom_post_type` all without having to set a new query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by adding a [query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). And then you can use something in pre_get_posts like this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'your_var' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I searched for `query_var` this came up and answered my question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/using-pre-get-posts-with-wp-query